# Zero-order hold in time... Possible?

Tags: sql, ms-access, view

Now, I have a table `X` in MS Access with the following fields:

```
X (Table)
- Dates   (Date/Time)
- Number1 (Double)
- Number2 (Long Integer)
```

Now suppose it has the following three records:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00,0.3,4
2000-01-01 00:02:00,0.5,5
2000-01-01 00:05:00,0.8,4
```

I want to write a view or something that could be called through OLE DB to return the following:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00,0.3,4
2000-01-01 00:01:00,0.5,5
2000-01-01 00:02:00,0.5,5
2000-01-01 00:03:00,0.8,4
2000-01-01 00:04:00,0.8,4
2000-01-01 00:05:00,0.8,4
```

I want it to "fill in" the missing minutes with the next available data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure SQL solution we can use a [Numbers] table with a single Long Integer column containing *at least* the values 0 through 1439, e.g.,

```
Integer
-------
      0
      1
      2
      3
...
   1439
```

We can start by creating a saved query in Access named **[X_with_minutes]** that retrieves the data in the [X] table and adds two columns showing: (1) just the date, and (2) the number of minutes past midnight...

```
SELECT X.*, 
    DateSerial(Year([Dates]), Month([Dates]), Day([Dates])) AS JustDate, 
    DateDiff("n", DateSerial(Year([Dates]), Month([Dates]), Day([Dates])), [Dates]) AS DayMinutes
FROM X;
```

...returning:

```
Dates                Number1  Number2  JustDate    DayMinutes
-------------------  -------  -------  ----------  ----------
2000-01-01 00:00:00      0.3        4  2000-01-01           0
2000-01-01 00:02:00      0.5        5  2000-01-01           2
2000-01-01 00:05:00      0.8        4  2000-01-01           5
```

We can create another saved query in Access named **[X_minutes_all]** to generate all of the minutes for each day in [X]...

```
SELECT DISTINCT X_with_minutes.JustDate, Numbers.Integer AS DayMinutes
FROM X_with_minutes, Numbers
WHERE Numbers.Integer BETWEEN 0 AND 1439;
```

...returning:

```
JustDate    DayMinutes
----------  ----------
2000-01-01           0
2000-01-01           1
2000-01-01           2
2000-01-01           3
...
2000-01-01        1439
```

Now we can create a query that returns the missing minutes and save that query as **[X_missing_minutes]**

```
SELECT * FROM  X_Minutes_all 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM X_with_minutes 
        WHERE X_with_minutes.JustDate=X_minutes_all.JustDate 
            AND X_with_minutes.DayMinutes=X_minutes_all.DayMinutes
    );
```

...returning:

```
JustDate    DayMinutes
----------  ----------
2000-01-01           1
2000-01-01           3
2000-01-01           4
2000-01-01           6
2000-01-01           7
2000-01-01           8
...
2000-01-01        1439
```

To find the "next" minute values for the missing minutes we need to find the smallest (MIN) value that exceeds the current one. We can create that query as follows, and save it as **[X_next_minutes]**...

```
SELECT X_missing_minutes.JustDate, 
    X_missing_minutes.DayMinutes,
    (
        SELECT MIN(DayMinutes) 
        FROM X_with_minutes 
        WHERE X_with_minutes.JustDate=X_missing_minutes.JustDate 
            AND X_with_minutes.DayMinutes>X_missing_minutes.DayMinutes
    ) AS NextMinute
FROM X_missing_minutes;
```

...returning...

```
JustDate    DayMinutes  NextMinute
----------  ----------  ----------
2000-01-01           1           2
2000-01-01           3           5
2000-01-01           4           5
2000-01-01           6      <NULL>
2000-01-01           7      <NULL>
2000-01-01           8      <NULL>
...
2000-01-01        1439      <NULL>
```

We can use that to return the [X] values for the missing minutes...

```
SELECT DateAdd("n", X_next_minutes.DayMinutes, X_next_minutes.JustDate) AS Dates, 
    X_with_minutes.Number1, X_with_minutes.Number2 
FROM X_next_minutes INNER JOIN X_with_minutes 
    ON X_next_minutes.JustDate=X_with_minutes.JustDate 
        AND X_next_minutes.NextMinute=X_with_minutes.DayMinutes;
```

...returning...

```
Dates                Number1  Number2
-------------------  -------  -------
2000-01-01 00:01:00      0.5        5
2000-01-01 00:03:00      0.8        4
2000-01-01 00:04:00      0.8        4
```

...and we can just tack on a UNION ALL with the original [X] to produce the final result...

```
SELECT DateAdd("n", X_next_minutes.DayMinutes, X_next_minutes.JustDate) AS Dates, 
    X_with_minutes.Number1, X_with_minutes.Number2 
FROM X_next_minutes INNER JOIN X_with_minutes 
    ON X_next_minutes.JustDate=X_with_minutes.JustDate 
        AND X_next_minutes.NextMinute=X_with_minutes.DayMinutes
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM X
ORDER BY 1;
```

...returning...

```
Dates                Number1  Number2
-------------------  -------  -------
2000-01-01 00:00:00      0.3        4
2000-01-01 00:01:00      0.5        5
2000-01-01 00:02:00      0.5        5
2000-01-01 00:03:00      0.8        4
2000-01-01 00:04:00      0.8        4
2000-01-01 00:05:00      0.8        4
```

Comment: A question... How would the performance of this hold up if we have ~200 records for each day and about three years' worth of data?

Comment: @HameerAbbasi This approach certainly *could* bog down on a large data set, but the only way to know for sure would be to try it.

Comment: I just got home, and I got around to reading your approach (earlier, I was on my cell phone). Although one can't deny it's brilliant, it won't work if, for example, the last minute of a day isn't 23:59:59. It won't fill in those minutes.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi True, but I was trying to make the results match those in the question and they didn't extend past the last observation for that day. The logic could be made to "wrap around" to a following day (as required to fill in the rest of the minutes until midnight), but given that you also have ~3 years of data that would expand the size of the intermediate queries significantly. Therefore you might be better off creating a table containing every minute of every day (~1.6 million rows), filling it in, indexing it appropriately, and then running straight SELECT queries on that table.